# how i can create right gradient between two divs

Tags: html, css

I have two blocks
http://imageshack.us/a/img203/9351/555el.png

how i can create gradiend between these blocks like this
http://imageshack.us/a/img521/1866/8585.png

this is my css and html code

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.fx6p1 {
  width: 580px;
  height: 721px;
  background: #EDEDED;
  margin: 40px 0 0 40px; 
  padding: 9px;
  }
div.fx6Ra {
    width: 200px;
    background: #333333;
    height: 560px;
    margin: 170px 0 0 589px;
}
</style>
<div class="fx6p1">
  <div class="fx6Ra">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy but not perfect way: [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow)

http://jsfiddle.net/yA3CX/

```css
div.fx6Ra {
    box-shadow:-10px 0px 25px #404040;
}
```

Hard way: [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3abefore) and [`line-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient)

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/yA3CX/2/</strike>

```css
div.fx6Ra:before,
div.fx6Ra::before {
    content:' ';
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:219px;
    left:633px;
    height:560px;
    width:15px;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right,black,transparent);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(to left,black,transparent);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(to left,black,transparent);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(to left,black,transparent);
    background-image:linear-gradient(to left,black,transparent);
}
```

or

http://jsfiddle.net/yA3CX/3/

```css
div.fx6Ra:before,
div.fx6Ra::before {
    content:' ';
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:-15px;
    height:560px;
    width:15px;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right,black,transparent);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(to left,black,transparent);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(to left,black,transparent);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(to left,black,transparent);
    background-image:linear-gradient(to left,black,transparent);
}
```

Comment: Correctly spotted that box-shadow is not perfect as it extends beyond top and bottom. May be easier to fix with a shadow inset in the other div, anyway ?

Comment: @vals I don't think so. Can you demonstrate on fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS shadow.

look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) this meight help you

Answer (score 0):

Just use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow):

```
div.fx6Ra {
    width: 200px;
    background: #333333;
    height: 560px;
    margin: 170px 0 0 589px;
    box-shadow: -8px 0px 8px 1px #888;
}
```

`box-shadow` has the following values:

```
box-shadow: x y blur spread color;
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3shPF/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 "box-shadow" style property will help for your requirement.
Syntax for the the box-shadow property is

```
box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;
```

please check the [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp). And try the style in online using [box-shadow style generator](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/)

Comment: `w3schools` is not a reliable resource. Please check [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It's working in Firefox and Chrome, I checked it.

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.fx6p1 {
  width: 580px;
  height: 721px;
  background: #EDEDED;
  margin: 40px 0 0 40px; 
  padding: 9px;
  }
div.fx6Ra {
    width: 200px;
    background: #333333;
    height: 560px;
    margin: 170px 0 0 589px;
    box-shadow: -10px 0 4px 0 #888888;
}
</style>
<div class="fx6p1">
  <div class="fx6Ra">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the highlight that you mentioned in your example (http://imageshack.us/a/img521/1866/8585.png), I'm assuming you're actually talking about the drop-shadow.

**To achieve a drop-shadow that looks exactly like on your image where it only appears on the left side of the box**, one way is to include an extra div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fx6p1">
    <div class="fx6Ra">
        <div class="dropshadow-leftonly"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.fx6p1 {
    width: 580px;
    height: 721px;
    background: #EDEDED;
    margin: 40px 0 0 40px;
    padding: 9px;
}
div.fx6Ra {
    position: relative;
    margin: 170px 0 0 579px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 210px;
    height: 560px;
}
.dropshadow-leftonly {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 560px;
    background: #333333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #ababab;
    float: right;
}
```

**Here's a working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/A4c4p/